# Posting tweets using Twitterizer

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitterizer

I am using twitterizer for posting tweets to a user's twitter account. It works fine but it is fully based on tokens (as you all know). This doesn't work in my case because Twitterizer redirects the user to the twitter page where the user logs and then using callbackurl the control is returned to our application.

My requirements are slightly different. I am storing user's twitter's account credentials in my database and then using those credentials I want to post the tweet.

Is this possible? So, in summary I don't want user to leave my site. They can configure their username and password in my application form and then I want to pick up those credentials and post a tweet.

Comment: @Merlyn Monroe: I have already registered my app. Not about about one time OAuth. Let me find that.

Comment: I changed it to an answer.  Also, that is not my name =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Twitterizer, but I believe you can register your app at twitter.com, do a one-time auth through OAuth, get and store the auth token, and use it permanently.

I can't speak from experience or authoritatively, but I believe storing their credentials in your DB is probably against Twitter's TOS.

See [the OAuth FAQ for Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq).

> How long does an access token last?
>
> We do not currently expire access tokens. Your access token will be invalid if a user explicitly rejects your application from their settings or if a Twitter admin suspends your application. If your application is suspended there will be a note on your application page saying that it has been suspended.

Comment: Ok! Let me find that option of one time auth.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, twitter has stopped allowing that kind of functionality now. The only way to connect is by making use of twitter OAuth.